# Using Multiple Textures In OpenGL(GLFW/GLAD)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glad

I'm working on an OpenGL project that is basically just a 2D painting right now. You can add/remove "blocks" from the canvas and do some other basic stuff. I'm trying to implement multiple textures and am having a hard time doing so. To be clear, I don't need multiple shaders, just different textures. Here's what my Block class looks like:

```
#pragma once

#include "shader_s.h"


class Texture {
    Shader* shader;
    unsigned char *data;
    int width, height, nrChannels;

    //Shader shader;


public:
    Texture(char* image) {
        shader = new Shader("shader.vs", "shader.fs");



        unsigned int texture1;

        glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        
        stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
        data = stbi_load(image, &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
        if (data)
        {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
        }
        stbi_image_free(data);




        shader->setInt("texture1", 0);


    }


public:
    Shader getShader() {
        return *shader;
    }

public:
    void use() {
        shader->use();
        
    }
};
```

and [this](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=includes/learnopengl/shader.h) is where the shader_s header comes from(learnopengl).

Basically, the main problem is that the code in the constructor regarding the OpenGL stuff gets overriden by the next texture(I think that's the problem). The result is that all Texture classes other than the last one created are ignored. I have no idea how to fix this because I'm not 100% sure what all the OpenGL functions do.

Comment: *"the OpenGL stuff gets overriden by the next texture"* - no. You've to create multiple texture objects (`texture1`, `texture2`, ...) before the rendering loop. Bind the proper texture object before you draw the geometry in the rendering loop (e.g. `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);`).

Comment: Ok, tried that out and it seems to work. Thanks.

Edit: I'm confused about one thing. Why does it not working if they are both using the same variable. They are both declared in individual class scopes so they should be considered as two different variables. Why does c++ need two indiviually named classes?

Comment: Most likely there is another bug in your application.